# Mysql named placeholders in python used in the IN clause

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I prefer to use named placeholders when hacking MySQL bound python code, but it seems that I can't get it just right with the `IN` clause. An example:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(db='test', user='test')
cur = con.cursor()
```

Three too simple examples:

```
# (#1) works fine, but I want placeholders.
cur.execute( """ update test
                 set    i = 999
                 where  SNO in (1, 2) """)

# (#2) works fine too, but still not enough placeholders.
cur.execute( """ update test
                 set    i = %(i)s
                 where  SNO in (1, 2) """, {'i' : 999})

# (#3) works, but did not pass the beauty check...
cur.execute( """ update test
                 set    i = %(i)s
                 where  SNO in ( %(a)s, %(b)s ) """, {'i' : 99,
                                                      'a' : 1,
                                                      'b' : 2})
```

This is what I really want, but it fail with: **Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

```
# (#4) This one fails with: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
cur.execute( """ update test
                 set    i = %(i)s
                 where  SNO in ( %(foo)s ) """, {'i'   : 999,
                                                 'foo' : [1, 2]})
```

Apparently I need *more magic*. It would be easy simply to move the problem to the application, implementing a loop in python, but I would rather avoid that.

Ah yes, performance is important too.

Comment: How about `",".join(['1', '2'])` instead of [1,2]? (Will work for normal python placeholders)

Comment: It's my understanding that it's preferred to use cursor placeholders for security reasons

Comment: Yup, but, as a workaround, you can call `mysqldb.escapestring` on your query arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MySQLdb` already handles the escaping of a sequence for you:

```
>>> con = MySQLdb.connect(db='test')
>>> con.literal([1,2,3])
('1', '2', '3')
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select * from test where id in %(foo)s", {'foo': [1,2,3]})
3L
>>> cur._executed
"select * from test where id in ('1', '2', '3')"
```

So by removing the parenthesis around your placeholder it should work - but only for sequences with more then one element, because a single element is formatted like this:

```
>>> con.literal([1])
('1',)
```

Inserted into a SQL query, the trailing comma makes it illegal SQL.

To work arount this, you could also define your own converter to convert a custom type to the representation you like:

```
import MySQLdb.converters
conv = MySQLdb.converters.conversions.copy()

class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self, *items):
        super(CustomList, self).__init__(items)

conv[CustomList] = lambda lst, conv: "(%s)" % ', '.join(str(item) for item in lst)

con = MySQLdb.connect(db='test', conv=conv)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from test where id in %(foo)s', {'foo': CustomList(0, 1, 2)})
print cur._executed
```

```
select * from test where id in (0, 1, 2)
```

This way the quotes around the list items are gone.

It would also work to just replace the converter for `list`, but that would change the behaviour for all lists and possibly introduce vulnerabilities. The above way of formatting a list would not be safe for a list containing strings, as it doesn't escape special characters.

To do that, you would have to recursively escape all items in the list:

```
>>> ...
>>> conv[list] = lambda lst, cv: "(%s)" % ', '.join(cv[type(item)](item, cv) for item in lst)
>>> con = MySQLdb.connect(..., conv=conv)
>>> con.literal([1, "it's working...", 2])
"(1, 'it\\'s working...', 2)"
```

Comment: Spot on! Removing the parenthesis were exactly the piece of _magic_ I were missing. About the custom converters, they are new to me, where do I need/use them? My code seems to run perfect already...

Comment: [converters](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.converters-module.html) can be used to support conversion of custom types. In this case it's not really needed, it's only to show how to control the conversion a custom type. The difference is that in the first case each int is quoted (string literals), in the second not (integer literals).

Comment: While it works perfect when I feed more than one item to the `IN` clause, it fails if the list (or tuple) only contains a single element.

Comment: ah, that's because a it's formatted as a tuple, and a so a single element is formatted as e.g. as `('1',)` - the trailing comma makes it illegal sql... So my second solution would be better because of this. I'll add this information to the answer.

Comment: +1 It's hard to find idiomatic examples of parameter binding with MySQLdb / mysqlclient. Here's all I could find about it on [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)